# Pass variable to a Fancybox in Rails with Content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, fancybox

I have this link in Rails:

```
<%= link_to "Add to Journal", add_post_journal_path(post), :method => :put %>
```

However I want transform this link to show a fancybox with the content listing my content to choose. First, I use this code:

```
<%= link_to "fancy", "#add_post", :class=>"fancybox" %>
```

but I have errors, because I want pass the actual post to fancybox, so I'm using this code: in `add_post.html.erb`:

```
<h1>Escolha o Jornal que deseja adicionar:</h1>
<ul>
<% current_user.journals.each do |journal| %>
  <li><%= link_to journal.name,add_post_complete_journal_path(journal),:remote=>true %> </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

and my controller is:

```
def add_post
  @journal_post = JournalsPosts.new
  session[:post_add] = params[:id]
end

def add_post_complete
  @journal_post = JournalsPosts.create(:post_id => session[:post_add],:journal_id => params[:id])

  respond_with @journal_post
end
```

How can I transform this code to use my content in my fancybox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add on your action add_post the next respond with js:

```
def add_post
    @journal_post = JournalsPosts.new
    session[:post_add] = params[:id]
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Add on a file on your views `add_post.js.erb` with the next content:

```
$.fancybox('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'path_to/add_post'))%>',
  {
    openEffect: "fade",
    closeEffect: "fade",
    autoSize: true,
    minWidth: 480,
    scrolling: 'auto',
  });
```

For example, you have add a partial `_add_post.html.erb` on your views. Now inside this partial you can write your code view:

```
#code for your view inside partial `add_post.html.erb`
<%= @journal_post %>
<h1>Escolha o Jornal que deseja adicionar:</h1>
<ul>
 .
 .
```

Regards!

Comment: Have a problem, when i click in the link to add:    `<%= link_to "Add to Journal", add_post_journal_path(post), :method => :put %>` this redirect to a page empty, in the console appear respond to html dont is because the method is put ? i insert the code to response in js but this dont response in js what is?

Comment: you have add `:remote=>true`. `<%= link_to "Add to Journal", add_post_journal_path(@journal_post), :method => :put, :remote=>true %>`